# Show validation message after coiming out of input field either by tab out/ mouse out in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a form where in i must show the validation message when i come out of the input field if the pattern i have entered is invalid. But here, it is showing validation message based on the keyinput, i tried with updatedOn:'blur' inside ts file but it didnt work for me along with the patterns as well.

Can anyone help me out, to make it show validation message when i come out of the tab.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phone-mask-directive-koe54t?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tel">Tel:</label>
        <input id="tel" class="form-control" phoneMask [preValue]="userForm.value.phone"  [phoneControl]="userForm.controls['phone']" formControlName="phone" maxlength="14" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid':submitted && detailsInfo.phone.invalid}">     
   <div *ngIf=" detailsInfo.phone.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="detailsInfo.phone.invalid">Please enter valid phone number</div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="submitted && detailsInfo.phone.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="detailsInfo.phone.errors.required">Phone number is required</div>
              </div>
    </div>
        <label for="tel">Cell:</label>
        <input id="tel" class="form-control" phoneMask [preValue]="userForm.value.fax"  [phoneControl]="userForm.controls['fax']" formControlName="fax" maxlength="14" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid':  detailsInfo.fax.invalid}">      
   <div *ngIf=" detailsInfo.fax.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="detailsInfo.fax.invalid">Please enter valid phone number</div>
              </div>
  <button (click)="save()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

TS:

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      phone:['',[Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/),Validators.required]],
      fax:['',Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/)],
    });
```

Here, for Phone Number, based on click of save button, the validation message will be shownup, if the pattern is invalid it must show error message for pattern validation as well.
I know it is because of submitted value in ngClass , but not finding how to resolve it.

I went through many answers but didnt get way to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in angular the Best way to do this is using a library like

**IntlTelInput**

It is essay to config and has a global directory where you can select default country 
and it validates the phone number using its database also formats the entered number with brackets and dash

I have personally used it and would recommend you to do the same

Dont forget to vote and accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: sorry i am not supposed to use any plugins

Answer (score 0):

Use `updateOn: 'blur'` while declaring the control

Try like this:

```
 this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      phone:['',[Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/),Validators.required]],
      fax: new FormControl('', {
            validators: [Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/)], updateOn: 'blur' })
      });
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phone-mask-directive-ved89e)**

Comment: Thanks for response, but here while typing i must retain the pattern and it must work same for phone number as well, i need to get error message when the phone number pattern is invalid

Comment: I showed you the way for fax only Add updateOn: 'blur' on phone number as well

Comment: ya, but it is not allowing me to type with the auto populated phone pattern

Comment: any idea how to implement along with the pattern?